# Book recommendation on traditional, pre-industrial homesteading

Tags: home, diy, farming

I am looking for references which document and explain how to do things without using electricity and all industrial technology.

If you have read ["The way home" by Mark Boyle](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/42515426-the-way-home), this would be the sort of stuff that he needs to know how to do. 
If you haven't, imagine you had to know how to butcher a roadkill deer, dig a hole for a post, do the laundry using ash, etc.

Essentially, pre-industrial homesteading and farming references.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a book, but until then, have you ever come across this youtube channel? [Townsends](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxr2d4As312LulcajAkKJYw) has videos not only about recipes but also about different techniques of building stuff around the house, in the good old 18th century way. I found them when I was watching videos about baking bread, they have a nice one about how they make an oven out of clay.

Answer (score 0):

You are right , it is a very wide subject and it is better to concentrate on one thing at a time and look up references for that, rather than look for a book which purports to teach you "natural living". For instance look up "How to prepare a rabbit for the pot." This will be slightly different to "How to prepare a pheasant for cooking." Game birds need to be "Hung" for a while, before they are "Pulled". Traditional farming methods are different according to where you live, the animals and plants you will use will be different, so try to find reference books written close to home. Once you know what plants and animals will thrive where you live, you can decide which you would like to have and look for a book on growing different beans, or raising goats. Many books have been written about "smallholdings," and these are usually very explicit and entertaining. You will hopefully also find websites and blogs from people in your own area, and they will give you advice.

Comment: This seems like a better comment on the question than an answer to it.